# React classname definition

Tags: reactjs, classname

is there any difference between `className = 'name'` and `className = {'name'}` in React? I ofc know that you can use variables in {}, but my question is specifically to string in those brackets `{''}`. I tried to simulate this in code and it looks to me that are both the same. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in both the notations if you are writing a single class name that is, `className="name"` is equal and the same as `className={'name'}`

However, we use this `{}` notation when we want to give a conditional class. For example:

`<p className={this.state.hidden ? "hidden" : ""}>Hello World</p>`

The above line gives the `<p>` tag a class of hidden if the state variable `hidden` is set to `true`. We use the the curly braces `{}` in React when we want to write JavaScript code in the render function. We could use it for concatenation of two string class names or conditional class names.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no difference. When you write {'name'}, it is interpreted as 'name'. Just like if you write {'name' + ' name2' }, it is interpreted as 'name name2'.